# What's the easiest way to create a feed in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, feed

I want to provide some dynamic content like an rss feed, so when they go to mydomain.com/fishcake.rss it runs some code on the server to generate it and returns it back.

I am guessing maybe an ashx file and something in the webconfig to associate it with the path I want, but I'm not totally sure. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the two answers until now are both good, I think your question is more about the dynamic part, rather than the feed structure itself. And you actually answered that yourself. The ASHX file is called an Http Handler, and that's the way to go about delivering dynamic content. Here's some more info:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The **easiest** way would be to use a library designed to create feeds.  I have used the [Argotic Syndication Framework](http://argotic.codeplex.com/) with success in the past.

[Here is a link](http://argotic.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Generating%20an%20RSS%20feed&referringTitle=Home) with a sample for creating an RSS feed with Argotic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use out of the box .NET libraries, check out [**SyndicationFeed**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed.aspx).

Here's a good example of how to [Create a Basic RSS Feed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412174.aspx).

(The example shows how that class can fit in with WCF, but the basic principles and code are there.)